# exercicio Erro de ponto flutuante

Tags: c, float

Tenho uma lista sobre erros de ponto flutuante e estou tendo certa dificuldade com uma das questões. Se alguém puder me ajudar, fico grato.

Para o código abaixo, preciso justificar qual será o motivo do erro.

```
int main () {
  double x;
  x = 0.;
  printf("x = %2.13lf\n",x);
  while ( x != 1.0 ) {
    x = x + 0.1;
    printf("x = %2.13lf\n",x);
 }
```

Penso que esteja relacionado com o arredondamento da soma. É isso mesmo ou tem algo a mais?

Comment: Erro de sintaxe: também falta um `}` para fechar o `main`

Answer (score 1):

[Testando](http://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_visual) o seguinte código e só alterando `2.13` para `2.20`

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int i;
    double x;
    i = 1;
    x = 0.;
    printf("exec %1li",i);
    printf("x = %2.20lf\n",x);
    while ( x != 1.0 ) {
        i++;
        x = x + 0.1;
        printf("exec %1li",i);
        printf("x = %2.20lf\n",x);
    }
}
```

---

A saída para `2.13`:

```
exec 1x = 0.0000000000000
exec 2x = 0.1000000000000
exec 3x = 0.2000000000000
exec 4x = 0.3000000000000
exec 5x = 0.4000000000000
exec 6x = 0.5000000000000
exec 7x = 0.6000000000000
exec 8x = 0.7000000000000
exec 9x = 0.8000000000000
exec 10x = 0.9000000000000
exec 11x = 1.0000000000000 // <- Valor a ser considerado, que na notação 10^13 acaba sendo interpretado como 1.0
exec 12x = 1.1000000000000
exec 13x = 1.2000000000000
exec 14x = 1.3000000000000
exec 15x = 1.4000000000000
exec 16x = 1.5000000000000
```

---

A saída para `2.20`:

```
exec 1x = 0.00000000000000000000
exec 2x = 0.10000000000000000555
exec 3x = 0.20000000000000001110
exec 4x = 0.30000000000000004441
exec 5x = 0.40000000000000002220
exec 6x = 0.50000000000000000000
exec 7x = 0.59999999999999997780
exec 8x = 0.69999999999999995559
exec 9x = 0.79999999999999993339
exec 10x = 0.89999999999999991118
exec 11x = 0.99999999999999988898 // <- Valor a ser considerado, que na notação 10^13 acaba sendo interpretado como 1.0
exec 12x = 1.09999999999999986677
exec 13x = 1.19999999999999995559
exec 14x = 1.30000000000000004441
exec 15x = 1.40000000000000013323
exec 16x = 1.50000000000000022204
```

Veja que a cada soma de `0.1` na verdade é acrescido `0.10000000000000000555`, onde dependendo da quantidade de casas decimais que se use para representar o valor, o compilador pode acabar arredondando.

Tente alterar a linha do `while` para `while ( x != 0.5 ) {` e você vera que o código não entrara em loop infinito porque o valor que foi acrescido nessa ultima execução literalmente sera `0.5` (`0.50000000000000000000` = `0.5` = `0.5000`).

Não diria que é um erro de arredondamento, e sim devido a `0.1` representar `0.10000000000000000555` a cada soma dentro do while.